# How can i get the name by ID in input type text?

Tags: php, html, foreach

i can call my input value using the `foreach ($sub_category as $k => $v)` and with the `value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" <?php if(in_array($v['id'], $sub_category_data)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $v['name'] ?>` but that was in select box my question here is that if i want to convert it into an input type textview how can i get the value?

```
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sub_category">Category:</label>
                  <?php $sub_category_data = json_decode($product_data['sub_category_id']); ?>
                  <select class="form-control select_group" id="sub_category_1" name="sub_category[]" onchange="getSubCategoryData(1)">
                    <?php foreach ($sub_category as $k => $v): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" <?php if(in_array($v['id'], $sub_category_data)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

what should i add to call the markup using the sub category id just like in the select box without using the foreach?

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="markup">Markup:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="markup" name="markup" disabled value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Markup">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="markup_value" name="markup_value" value="" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish? What is the end goal? Why are you converting a select element into a text input element?

Comment: Does `$sub_category[0]['id']` do what you're asking??

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles i just wanna know how can i call the markup in input text, my select is running as i expected and i just wanna try it in input type text, how is the program should be if i want to call the markup using the subcategory id without foreach like in select?

Comment: I'm still unclear. An HTML `<select>` is used because you have multiple choices. Do you want to have multiple `<input>` elements? Or, if you just want a single one, is it just the first item from the array? Or, do you want a single `<input>` and somehow combine all the items in the array, possibly using a comma or similar, and use that for the value?

Comment: What's the difference between `$sub_category` and `$sub_category_data` ? Apparently `$sub_category` is an array of all possible options, with `id` and `name` values. — How many of each `$sub_category` item do you expect will be in `$sub_category_data` ? only one?

Comment: @ChrisHaas i only want a single one and i want to call the 1 column using the id without foreach like in select?

Comment: You'll need to look at the index of `$sub_category`. You can do this by doing `var_dump($sub_category);`. I'm guessing the first index is probably `0`, but it could be `'cheese'` or `934` or anything. Once you know the index you can reference it directly such as `$sub_category[0]` or `$sub_category['cheese']`. It appears that this is an array of arrays, so you'd fully want to do `$sub_category[0]['id']` (assuming `0` is the index).